# Logging all ssh tunnel data

Tags: logging, ssh-tunnel

Having an SSH server through which multiple users tunnel all the traffic, how can I log (write) all the traffic (mostly interested in unencrypted HTTP one)?

UPD: not all traffic should be logged, only that from SSH tunnel (the server is used for other things too).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with tshark, just install tshark and run the following command:

> tshark -i eth0 -f "http" -w httpcapture.cap

it writes all the captured http traffic on eth0 to httpcapture.cap file which you can later easily analyse.

Comment: Why is this "not a real serverfault question"?

Comment: I went ahead and edited that sentence out, as it made no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Using the program TCPDump, which captures network traffic going over a network connection and can log it to a file: http://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/

Or by passing the HTTP traffic through a proxy, e.g. Squid.